# Show first 10 rows while loading more 4000 rows from data table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

While loading a page with more than 4000 rows (from a database) the browser (IE, Firefox and Chrome) freezes auntil all the data are rendered. At which point the Data table (from jquery.dataTables.min.js library) is displayed and the browser is responsive and my filters work normally.

The values ​​are being brought directly from the database

Is there a way to avoid the browser getting into "non-responsive" mode?

Comment: What's the question? **4000 raw before component datatable show the first 10 raw** - for that I load the Javascript last, at the end of the page do your `$("#myTable").Datatable();` at the end of the _layout.cshtml. If you only want ten records you'll need to use the AJAX methods for partial dataset loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try server-side paging for `DataTables`.

1. Client

   ```
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Id</th>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Sku</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
   </table>

   @section Scripts{
       <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>


       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#example').DataTable({
                   "processing": true,
                   "serverSide": true,
                   "lengthMenu": [[2, 4, 8, -1], [2, 4, 8, "All"]],
                   "ajax": {
                       url: "https://localhost:44376/api/product/products",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   },
                   columns: [
                       {
                           data: "id",
                       },
                       {
                           data: "title"
                       },
                       {
                           data: "sku",
                       }
                   ]
               });
           });
       </script>
   }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
   [HttpGet("Products")]
   public ResponseVM AllProducts(RequestVM request)
   {
       var count = _context.Products.Count();
       var data = _context.Products.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length).ToList();
       return new ResponseVM
       {
           Draw = request.Draw,
           RecordsTotal = count,
           RecordsFiltered = count,
           Data = data
       };
   }
   ```
3. Models

   ```
   public class RequestVM
   {
       [FromQuery]
       public int Draw { get; set; }
       [FromQuery]
       public int Start { get; set; }
       [FromQuery]
       public int Length { get; set; }
   }
   public class ResponseVM
   {
       public int Draw { get; set; }
       public int RecordsTotal { get; set; }
       public int RecordsFiltered { get; set; }
       public object Data { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Comment: Tks by the answer, it work!!!! but the field "search" don't run and how change Id rows to  <td><a id-route= id> ??